# Connecting R to Snowflake through ODBC

Tags: sql, r, odbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have been consistently receiving the same error while trying to create a connection between R and Snowflake using an ODBC driver. The error that I'm receiving says:

'''Error during wrapup: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 00000: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'Snowflake' : file not found
Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart'''

The instructions given by Snowflake to connect a driver are rather cut and clear - but provides little insight on what to do with errors. Can anyone lead me as to where to go given this error?

Comment: Can you indicate in what environment are you trying to access Snowflake?

Comment: Please include the code you are using to connect to Snowflake

Comment: The error comes from R odbc package, not Snowflake ODBC driver ([nanodbc.cpp](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/blob/main/src/nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp)). If you installed R odbc can you show us the output of **odbc::odbcListDrivers()** and **odbc::odbcListDataSources()**?

Answer (score 4):

This smells like a configuration issue. Your driver manager, unixODBC, isn't able to locate the Snowflake driver. (The Snowflake documentation says on MacOS to use iODBC. Don't. It won't work with the odbc R package.)

1. Check that unixODBC is findable. Run `odbcinst -j` in a terminal. If it works, you will know that you have unixODBC properly installed, and it will give you the paths to your various configuration files.
2. On to checking configuration. [This](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/odbc-linux.html#step-4-configure-the-odbc-driver) is the documentation for configuring on Linux using unixODBC. If you are using MacOS the same general instructions apply, but the file extensions will change from `.so` to `.dylib` . Since it's saying it can't find the file, I'm thinking that using full paths might resolve this for you. It's also possible that there's some issue with how you are specifying the driver.

Also, it looks like it's searching for a file named 'Snowflake'. I'm thinking you've got `Driver=Snowflake` somewhere in one of your config files. Best change that to `Driver=<path>/<to>/<driver>/libSnowflake.dylib` (or `.so` if you're on Linux). Do this in all the places where you have `Driver=Snowflake`.